# How to get array of all keys which contain certain substring from dictionary array in JS?

Tags: javascript

How can I get an array of all keys which contain certain substring from dictionary array in JS? I tried to use `reduce` and `map` and `filter`, but don't know how to use those for this particular problem...

**Input**

`[{id: 0, hello: 1}, {id: 1, world: 2}, {id: 2, bye: 3}]`

**Expected output (Get all keys with substring 'l')**

`['hello', 'world']`

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Consider using `map` and `includes`?

Comment: Also use `Object.keys()`

Comment: @evolutionxbox `map()` is not correct, since the number of elements in the result is not the same as the input array.

Comment: @Barmar good point.

Comment: @Cat No, he wants the key `hello` from the object `{id: 0, hello: 1}`

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: I see that now. I'm deleting my mistaken comment

Comment: It's not homework. I tried to use  `reduce` and `map`, but didn't know how to use those for this particular problem. Couldn't find any question on SO with same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `.reduce` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is great for this.

Here, we get the keys for each object in the array, and if a key contains the desired substring, we push it to the array that is being returned from each iteration of `reduce`.

```js
const input =[
  {id: 0, hello: 1}, {id: 1, world: 2}, {id: 2, bye: 3}
];

console.log(getKeysWithSubstring(input, "l"));

function getKeysWithSubstring(arrayOfObjs, needle){
  return arrayOfObjs.reduce( (previousLoopOutput, currentObj) => {

    // Renaming the output array for clarity
    const thisLoopOutput = previousLoopOutput;

    Object.keys(currentObj).forEach(haystack => {
      // It's possible that many keys in the same object will be pushed
      if(haystack.includes(needle)){
        thisLoopOutput.push(haystack);
      }
    });
    return thisLoopOutput;
  }, []); // First time through loop, `previousLoopOutput` argument will be `[]`
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot!  I tried to replace your `forEach` with `filter`: ```return Object.keys(currentObj).filter((key) => key.includes("l"));``` The output seems to be correct, but I am not sure if this actually does what I need. Any idea?

Comment: I updated the snippet to clarify why that doesn't work. Basically, the `.reduce` method calls a function once for each element in the array. The value of the `lastLoopOutput` argument that gets passed in with the current element is whatever was returned from the last call. This is why I set it to return the same output array each time (possibly with new strings added) instead of returning a filtered version of the current object's keys -- because the current object's keys would not make a suitable input for the next iteration. (Check the MDN documentation I linked to for more details.)